# Remove duplicated values in column, leaving only those which are higher in terms of rows

Tags: vba, excel

There is a sheet `scr` where column `P` has the following view:

```
P1=100
P2=100
P3=100
P4=100
P4=101
P5=101
P6=102
P7=102
P8=102
```

, meaning there are blocks of unique values. I need to leave only the upper value (here - `P1`, `P4`, `P6`). The other duplicated values should be erased. Therefore, I made the code below, but it does not work and gives no error.

```
Sub Test()

Dim wb1 As Workbook                                                 
Set wb1 = ActiveWorkbook                                            
Set src = wb1.Sheets("Modules_List")                                

Application.ScreenUpdating = False                                  
Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual
Dim i As Long
Dim k As Integer
With src
    For i = 1 To 100
        For k = 1 To 100
            If .Cells(i, "P").Value = .Cells(i + k, "P").Value Then .Cells(i + k, "P").Value = ""
        Next k
    Next i
End With
Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic
Application.ScreenUpdating = True


End Sub
```

Comment: Why can't you do remove duplicates via toolbar?

Comment: @findwindow He wants the cells empty not deleted, this is a on going question from [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33832170/copy-matched-row-and-rows-below-it-if-column-a-is-empty?noredirect=1#comment55439156_33832170)

Comment: @findwindow This code is a apart of bigger action [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33832170/copy-matched-row-and-rows-below-it-if-column-a-is-empty). For purpose of size reduction, I test it first as a separate Sub. I have added the duplicates myself, as was suggested in the thread under the link, but now I need to remove them. Automatically, as a part of one action. I try to implement this approach instead of copying it to array, since I think I will be able to apply it also to the Destination folder (see link)

Comment: Scott's on it. You're in good hands.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is your entire code over you last three questions.

```
Sub Copy_Data_by_Criteria()

    Dim wb1 As Workbook
    Dim wb2 As Workbook
    Dim src As Worksheet
    Dim Dst As Worksheet
    Dim src2 As Worksheet


    Set wb1 = ActiveWorkbook
    Set wb2 = Workbooks.Open(Filename:="C:\Test.xlsx")
    Set src = wb1.Sheets("Sheet1")
    Set Dst = wb2.Sheets("Sheet1")
    Set src2 = wb1.Sheets("Base 1")

    Dim LastRow As Long
    Dim r As Range
    Dim CopyRange As Range
    Dim Crit As Range
    Dim strValue As Variant
    LastRow = src.Cells(src.Rows.Count, "P").End(xlUp).Row

    For Each Crit In src2.Range("G10:G" & 30)
        If Crit <> "" Then
            For Each r In src.Range("P6:P" & LastRow)

                If r <> 0 Then strValue = r

                If strValue = Crit Then
                    If CopyRange Is Nothing Then
                            Set CopyRange = r.EntireRow
                    Else
                            Set CopyRange = Union(CopyRange, r.EntireRow)
                    End If
                End If
            Next r
        End If
    Next Crit
    If Not CopyRange Is Nothing Then
    CopyRange.Copy Dst.Range("A1")
    End If

End Sub
```

As to why your current code did not do what you wanted, Since you looped down to add the values you need to loop up to remove them:

```
Sub Test()

Dim wb1 As Workbook
Set wb1 = ActiveWorkbook
Set src = wb1.Sheets("Modules_List")

Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual
Dim i As Long
Dim k As Integer
With src
    For i = 100 To 1
        If .Cells(i, "P").Value = .Cells(i - 1, "P").Value Then .Cells(i, "P").Value = ""
    Next i
End With
Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic
Application.ScreenUpdating = True


End Sub
```

Comment: @Meursau1t I edited the first code to get rid of the loop to fill in the blanks.

Comment: @Meursau1t I re-edited it so that there is no need to make changes to the source sheet at all.  Therefore no need to change anything back.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. It did not work until I changed LastRow in `For Each r In src.Range("P6:P" & LastRow)` to some constant. But anyways this is a perfect solutions. Now I have to spent a day to understand how it functions. Thanks again for a great lesson. Hope one day I can repay it here)